# Add Custom properties to ClaimsPrincipal user in asp.net core 2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

As per description on title, I have created a class which derived from `ClaimsPrincipal` and have additional properties:

```
public class CustomeUser: ClaimsPrincipal
{
   // additional properties
}
```

Wrote a middleware and assigned values to that from the claims:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
   // context to read header and assign to custome properties
   context.User = new CustomeUser() {
                         ClientIP = /*reading from claims*/,
                         UserId = /*reading from claims*/};
}
```

and in configuration service add following line to get `HttpContext` to fetch that custom user properties from controller in start up class.

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

from controller to fetch custome user properties

```
public BaseController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
   customeUser = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User as CustomeUser;
}
```

Is this a correct approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `IHttpContextAccessor` if you access `HttpContext` from a controller. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase` class from which controllers inherit (through Controller class) has `HttpContext` property. So your code could be changed as:

```
public BaseController()
{
   customeUser = HttpContext.User as CustomeUser;
}
```

All the rest seems good. `HttpContext.User` will contain instance of `CustomeUser` that you filled in `Invoke()` method so that nasty type conversion to `CustomeUser` will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Verymuch for the sugession but soon after I run the project I got HttpContext is null.I think I wonted to have IHttpContextAccessor injection here.any idea codefuller ?

Comment: Sorry for this inaccuracy. HttpContext will have `null` value in Controller constructor however it is filled if you call it from controller action.

Comment: how would you suggest doing this without the cast in the BaseController?

Comment: If you want to use a class derived from `ClaimsPrincipal` and avoid type cast, then you should have some field of `CustomUser` type where created user instances are stored. One of the option - use some global dictionary of `CustomUser` objects created by authentication middleware. But I'd keep away from such solution. Cast is much less evil in this case.