# C#: Add Custom Properties In HttpContextAccessor

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is there a way to add Custom properties in HttpContextAccessor in C# Net Core?

Say, create new property called: Favoritefood Property, or CreatedByUser (coming from special function) and assign a value?
this is simple example below,

We want to eventually bring custom properties into the DbContext layer, not only audit related, etc.

```
public class AuditableDbContext: DbContext
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public AuditableDbContext(DbContextOptions<AuditableDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base(options)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    private void ApplyCreatedBy()
    {
        var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<IFood>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added);
        foreach (var entity in modifiedEntities)
        {
            entity.Property("Food").CurrentValue = GetFoodMethod();
        }
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ApplyCreatedBy();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

**Resources:**

[Log UserName and IP with Custom Properties in Application Insight .Net Core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854319/log-username-and-ip-with-custom-properties-in-application-insight-net-core-2-1)

[Add Custom properties to ClaimsPrincipal user in asp.net core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47565882/add-custom-properties-to-claimsprincipal-user-in-asp-net-core-2)

Comment: `HttpContextAccessor` is not sealed. You can write your own class that inherits from it and add whatever properties you want.

Comment: hi @JohnWu feel free to write in answer, and I can send points, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not 100% sure what your example has to do with adding custom things into the http context.
But yes, HttpContext has an items collection which you can use to store context specific state information.

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["key"] = "some random value";
```

You can get the context via the ContextAccessor.